# Convert subquery to single value in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of places. I need to insert into a guestbook a note for each one.

I have the following code:

```
begin
  for rec in (
    SELECT p.place_id FROM Places p
    WHERE p.place_id NOT IN(
            SELECT DISTINCT v.place_id FROM Visits v
        )
  ) loop
    INSERT INTO Guestbook
    VALUES (
      rec.place_id,
      (
           SELECT MAX(person_id) INTO my_id
           FROM Persons
           WHERE name LIKE 'My Name'
           GROUP BY person_id;
      ),
      'My comment'
  );
  end loop;
end;
```

The problem is that the insert doesn't work, because it seeing the subquery as a column. But even if I try to call MAX() on it, it won't see it as a single value. I need that subquery to return just one single value, so I can insert it into the Guestbook

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like this.

```
SELECT (SELECT MAX(person_id) FROM Persons) INTO my_id
       FROM Persons
       WHERE name LIKE 'My Name'
       GROUP BY person_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always include the full error message you're getting - in this case, you've got several errors in this part:

```
SELECT MAX(person_id) INTO my_id
       FROM Persons
       WHERE name LIKE 'My Name'
       GROUP BY person_id;
```

- the semicolon ';' marks the end of the SQL statement - since your statement continues on the next line, you have to remove it
- `INTO my_id` is necessary if you want to store the results of a SQL statement in a PL/SQL variable. Since it's part of a more complex statement, it doesn't make sense here and must be removed.
- using `MAX(person_id)` together with `GROUP BY person_id` doesn't make sense; I assume you want `GROUP BY name`

Finally, unless you want to write it as a loop for educational purposes, this can (and should) be rewritten as a simple INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO Guestbook(place_id, person_id, comment)
SELECT
  p.place_id,
  (
       SELECT MAX(person_id) 
       FROM Persons
       WHERE name LIKE 'My Name'
       GROUP BY name
  ),
  'My comment'
FROM Places p
WHERE p.place_id NOT IN (
   SELECT v.place_id FROM Visits v
);
```

This is shorter, clearer and much more efficient. I've also explicitly enumerated the columns in the `INTO` clause - this ensures the code will still work if columns are added to the target table in the future.